# Browser encodes query string twice

Tags: php, redirect, urlencode

i'm having some troubles with encoding query string during redirect.

Params:

```
(
    [pg_salt] => 54ed95e0df7f2
    [pg_merchant_id] => 6430
    [pg_order_id] => 1016156
    [PAYMENT_SYSTEM] => Test
    [pg_lifetime] => 86400
    [pg_amount] => 8512.00
    [pg_description] => Order ID: 11111
    [pg_user_phone] => 
    [pg_user_contact_email] => test@test.com
    [pg_user_email] => test@test.com
    [pg_user_ip] => 11.11.111.111
    [pg_request_method] => GET
    [pg_success_url_method] => AUTOPOST
    [pg_failure_url_method] => AUTOGET
)
```

Then im redirecting user with header location and building query string via http_build_query

```
header('Location: https://test.com/test.php?'.http_build_query($arrRequest));
```

The URL looks this way:

```
http://www.test.com/test.php?pg_salt=54ed91b876393&pg_merchant_id=6430&pg_order_id=1016156&PAYMENT_SYSTEM=Platron&pg_lifetime=86400&pg_amount=8512.00&pg_description=Order+ID%253A+1016156&pg_user_phone=&pg_user_contact_email=test%2540test.com&pg_user_email=test%2540test.com&pg_user_ip=11.11.111.11&pg_request_method=GET&pg_success_url_method=AUTOPOST&pg_failure_url_method=AUTOGET&pg_sig=7351aa0b8607612d85cbd322b4d76803
```

Lets take an example on email.

```
test%2540test.com
```

%2540 is encoded %40 (@).

Why during redirect symbols like %40(@) are being encoded to %2540 and how to avoid that?

Comment: [Read out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393229/40-on-click-turns-to-2540)

Comment: Didnt help me. I'm not encoding twice. Maybe the problem is in http_build_query, function is encoding the string, and browser encodes it for second time. I tried to collect query string myself, without using http_build_query function, but still im getting twice encoded sybmols. How can i solve this problem?